# Python logging: Best way to organize logs in different files?

Tags: python, logging, rotation, handler, hierarchy

I have different loggers (log1, log2, log3, ..., logN) which are being logged to "registry.log" for a big N. I would like to divide "registry.log" into N different files as "registry.log" can become really large.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically, for instance, with a  rotating handler?

Comment: [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler)

Comment: But how? So far, I have only been able to do that according to the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `logging.Handler` subclass which determines which file to write to based on the details of the event being logged, and write the formatted event to that file.